# 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'coalesce' or 'repartition'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am running pyspark in AWS jupyter notebook. When I want to save the dataframe in S3 I am having partition by each line which is weird. I am looking to save the dataframe as it is.

```
df.write.repartition(1).format('parquet').mode("overwrite").save(output_s3_path)
```

#i also tried `.coalesce(1)`

If i need to upgrade `aws-java-sdk:1.7.4` to `aws-java-sdk:1.11.199` and
`hadoop-aws:2.7.7` to `hadoop-aws:3.0.0`

**Please tell me how to do it aws cloud?**

Comment: move `.coalesce(1)` before `.write`: `df.coalesce(1).write.format....`